# Navigate dynamic content horizontaly (ListViews)

Tags: android, listview

sorry for the confusing title. I will try to explain my problem.

My app displays some content day-wise in a ListView. The user is able to switch days back and forth (e.g. by swiping his finger to the left/right). Now I want to implement some nice transition effect (like the new Android market has).

The problem is, that the content is generated dynamically and it can take a while to load. Also you can move (theoretically) infinite days to to past or to the future.

How can I implement a nice looking transition that is responsive and also tells the user, that some work is done in the background.

Just to clarify, I'm not asking how a ListView or an AsyncTask works, but rather for design concepts for my idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you mean, I think you should try and preload in background the previous and following page, and keep them in memory ready to come in with the swipe.
Every time you change day you would recycle one page of data to load a new one (in one direction or another).
Obviously the user can still swipe too fast and you won't have time to preload things, but in that case I don't think you can do anything better than transitioning in the page with a nice spinner in it (not a blocking dialog).

Comment: How exactly would I realize the spinner thing? Would I have to deal with two ListViews at a time?

Comment: For the spinner: a [Frame animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame) in the middle of the screen should do it, and you dismiss it when the data is ready. It's enough to hide that and show the list instead.
For the list: if you want a transition where you see both screen at the same time, during the animation, then you will need to have two lists yes. But what you preload in the meantime is the adapter data for the previous and following screen.